# Benign data race condition with two threads

Tags: multithreading, race-condition

Is this a race condition?

```
class A {
   int x; 

   update() {
      x = 5; 
   }

   retrieve() {
      y = x; 
   }
}
```

If update() and retrieve() are called by two different threads without any locks being held, given that there is at least one write in two accesses of a shared variable, this can be classified as a race condition. But is this truly a problem during runtime?

Comment: What language? Or is it a language-agnostic question?

Comment: Calling a gross race like this "benign" is like calling a tiger a big pussy-cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without locks, three things can happen:

1. `y` gets the new value of `x` (5).
2. `y` gets the old value of `x` (most likely 0).
3. if writes into `int` are not atomic, then `y` can get any other value.

In Java, reads to an `int` are atomic, so the third option cannot happen. No guarantee about the atomicity in other languages.

With locking, the first two options can happen as well.

There is an extra challenge depending on the memory model, though. In Java, if a write is not synchronized, it can be arbitrarily delayed up until the next synchronisation point (the end of a `synchronized` block or an access to a `volatile` field). Similarly, reads can be arbitrarily cached up from the previous synchronisation point (the start of a `synchronized` block or an access to a `volatile` field). This can easily result in problems arising from stale cache. The end effect is that the second option can happen even if the first one was supposed to.

In Java, always use `volatile` with fields that can be accessed from other threads, or you'll be facing hard-to-debug race conditions arising from memory access reordering. The same warning applies in other languages that use a memory model similar to the one in Java - you may need to tell the compiler to not do these optimisations.

Comment: In C++, volatile does not guarantee any kind of synchronization or memory barrier. All it does is prevent certain kinds of optimizations. I have heard that VC++ gratuitously creates a memory barrier, but that is not standard.

Comment: @JiveDadson then it's not really an equivalent of Java's `volatile`. Rewritten.

Comment: @JiveDadson Also if the `volatile` keyword does not cut it then I don't know what will. Microsoft compilers do guarantee this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd(v=vs.80).aspx